# Double Apple ID

Tags: iphone, apple-id

My iPhone 4s was recently stolen and I immediately changed my Apple ID password. Now I have an iPhone 5 and even though at first they asked for my regular Apple ID to restore backup, after then another Apple Id appear and I don't recognized it at all. When I want to download an app, the Apps store asks me for both Apple ID accounts.

Answer (score 1):

The question is little unclear.
However, if you want to get rid of Unknown Apple ID, sign out of iTunes & App Stores and iCloud from your phone:
Go to `Settings > iTunes & App Stores`
Tap the very first `Apple ID: abc@example.com`
`Sign Out`
Similarly, in order to sign Out from iCloud.
Go to `Settings > iCloud`
Select `Sign Out` which is at very last.
And now try logging back in using your APPLE ID.